# Преобразовать строку в массив, создать набор на основе массива, найти сколько раз каждый символ встречается в исходном массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, set

При нажатии button выполняете функцию. Функция должна преобразовать строку в массив, причем каждая буква - отдельный элемент массива. Потом создать набор на основе массива. Затем, перебирая набор поэлементам, найти сколько раз каждый символ встречается в исходном массиве. Результат - в виде объекта типа { символ : количество, символ : количество } вывести в консоль и возвратить.
пример результата для строки 'Hello ho'
{ "H" : 1, 'e' : 1, 'l' : 2, "o" : 2, " ": 1}

```js
let str13 = 'The name conjures up visions of plum pudding and Christmas punch quaint coaching inns and cozy firesides but also of orphaned and starving children';


const f13 = () => {
    let array = Array.from(str13);
        let set = new Set(array);
            for (let arr of set) {

            }
}

document.querySelector('.b-13').onclick = () => {
    console.log(f13());
}
```

```html
<section>
       <p><b>Task 13.</b></p>
       <button class="button-primary b-13">Task-13</button>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фильтруйте массив по символу и количество отфильтрованных элементов и будет результатом:

```js
let str13 = 'The name conjures up visions of plum pudding and Christmas punch quaint coaching inns and cozy firesides but also of orphaned and starving children';

let array = Array.from(str13);
let set = new Set(array);
let result = {};
for (let symb of set) {
  result[symb] = array.filter(s => s === symb).length;
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с reduce

```js
let s = 'The name conjures...';

console.log([...s].reduce((a,b)=>{ a[b] ? a[b]++ : a[b] = 1; return a },{}))
```